# How to apply aggregate addition/arithmetic and multiplication/product based on condition in one column?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let's assume we have this 'table' here:

| Time_Order | Logic | Number | Accumulated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Add | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | Add | 30 | 50 |
| 3 | Add | 50 | 100 |
| 4 | Multiply | 0.8 | 80 |
| 5 | Multiply | 0.5 | 40 |
| 6 | Add | 10 | 50 |

Accumulated is the results of Adding or Multiplying based on all the previous records, so in Time_Order 3 we accumulated (50 + 30 + 20) = 100, then in Time_Order 4 I want to multiply by the 0.8 so I get 100 * 0.80 = 80, then Time_Order 5 I multiply the 80 by 0.5 and get 40. I go back to Add in Time Order 6 and get 40 + 10 = 50

I have something like:

```
Select a.*, case when Logic = 'Add' then sum(Number) over (Order by Time_Order)
            when Logic = 'Multiply' then Exp(Sum(ln(Accumulated * (1+Number)))) as Accumulated
from table a
```

The above won't work because I have 'Accumulated' within itself in the Multiply logic, so this is the exact problem, when faced with a conditional statement like this, how can i shift back and forth between 'add' and 'multiply' such that the accumulated number is remembered what it is from the previous row.

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: It's Redshift to be specific. Which won't let me do recursions

Comment: Then please update the tag accordingly

Comment: Done, should be good now